# Laravel dynamic class usage

Tags: php, html, laravel, oop

I need implement a system for class calling like this:

Imagine there is a class Calendar.php handling database queries (or a model if you like) which should be used by default. If there is a need to implement some new behaviour I would like to implement a class MaterialCalendar.php which will extend the Calendar.php class so I will be able to use all the methods from the Calendar.php in the newly created MaterialCalendar.php with overriding parent methods if needed.

The issue is how to implement this kind of behaviour used anywhere in the code, in a view or in a controller:

if (child class exists) { use child class } else { use default parent class }

This behaviour above in pseudocode should be dynamic, so if there is no MaterialCalendar.php Calendar.php should be used by default, if MaterialCalendar.php exists then that should be used. It needs to be dynamic, irrelevant of the class names used in this example.

Comment: There are objects implementing those classes or static classes?

Comment: @MaciejSikora no they are NOT static

Comment: If not static then You can check variable class by using http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.instanceof.php

Comment: @MaciejSikora maybe I wasn't clear enough, imagine you want to render a table in html from data you get from a controller (Calendar.php or MaterialCalendar.php if it exists).. if MaterialCalendar.php exists then I want to use that class to get data from database and hand it on to html rendering or if MaterialCalendar.php does not exist then I want to use Calendar.php to handle the above

Comment: @MaciejSikora that check if an instantiated object is an instance of a given class. If I've understood the question, he want to know if a class exist. That require that the language provide reflection; for example java allows this with Class.forName("name_of_class").

Answer (score 1):

Define interface to guarantee that your code will work with any implementation of ICalendar:

```
interface ICalendar {
    public function method1();
    public function method2();
}
```

Create implementations:

```
class Calendar implements ICalendar {
    public function method1() {}
    public function method2() {}

}

class MaterialCalendar extends Calendar {
    public function method1() {}
    public function method2() {}
}
```

Simple container

```
class SimpleContainer {
    private static $binds = [];

    public static function bind($interface, $class) {
        self::$binds[$interface] = $class;
    }

    public static function make($interface) {
        if (array_key_exists($interface, self::$binds)) {
            return new self::$binds[$interface];
        }

        throw new \Exception("Interface is not binded");
    }
}
```

Somewhere in bootstrap you should identify what class to bind to the interface like:

```
SimpleContainer::bind(ICalendar::class, MaterialCalendar::class);
```

Use the following code in all places where you need to get calendar object:

```
SimpleContainer::make(ICalendar::class);
```

Comment: Great use of design patterns and overall concept, but for containers Laravel's service container is much more flexible.

Comment: @samrap You are right. I missed the point that Laravel is used or maybe it was updated later. My solutions is just to describe the idea but in real app where Laravel involved I recommend to use Laravel standard components where container is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Andrej is off to a good start, but there is no need to design a container for this purpose. Laravel ships with a more than capable [container](https://laravel.com/docs/master/container) in which you can bind implementations to interfaces.

Using Andrej's interface and concrete classes, you could create a [service provider](https://laravel.com/docs/master/providers#writing-service-providers) that binds the class you want to the `ICalendar` interface:

(Within the provider's register method):

```
$this->app->bind('App\Contracts\ICalendar', 'App\Models\MaterialCalendar');
```

Of course, it is here that you will conditionally decide which class to bind to the interface (see function [`class_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php)).

From this point, you can rely on Laravel's container to inject this dependency wherever you need it. For example, in a `CalendarController`'s `store` method, you could simply [type hint](https://laravel.com/docs/master/container#automatic-injection) the *interface* and Laravel will automagically give you an instance of the concrete class that you bound to it:

```
use App\Contracts\ICalendar;

class CalendarController extends Controller
{
    ...

    public function store(Request $request, ICalendar $calendar)
    {
        // Code...
    }
}
```

I definitely recommend reading the documentation on the [container](https://laravel.com/docs/master/container) as well as [providers](https://laravel.com/docs/master/providers). Something of interest to you might be [Contextual Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/master/container#contextual-binding) in which you can conditionally bind implementations to interfaces.